# How to prove that $(x-3)^{\frac {1} {2}}=\frac{10}{x-5}$ has at least one real root?

Tags: calculus

How to prove that $(x-3)^{\frac {1} {2}}=\frac{10}{x-5}$ has at least one real root?

I know that you have to let $f(x)={(x-3)^{\frac {1} {2}}}$ and $g(x)=\frac{10}{x-5}$

then you let $h(x)=f(x)-g(x)=0$

I know I must use the intermediate value theorem but I cant find the $x$ intervals (need 2) of this graph which is needed for the proof

Comment: Welcome to MSE. To ask a question here you should use mathjax (Which is the way we write equations here), [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is a tutorial (It might seem like a lot of work but it is really simple). anyway there is no need to worry because I edited the question and used Latex.

Comment: For $x\to 5^+$, $\lim_{x\to5^+} f(x) = \sqrt 2$ and $\lim_{x\to5^+} g(x) = \infty$. While for $x=15$, $f(15) = \sqrt{12}$ and $g(15) = 1$.

Answer (score 2):

Rewrite the equation as $(x-5)\sqrt{x-3} = 10$. Notice that at $x=5$, the LHS equals $0 < 10$. Now take a large $x$, e.g. $x=100$, indeed we have LHS $> 10$. By continuity of LHS function, we proved that the equation must have at least one real root (for some $x \in (5,100)$, IVT).

Answer (score 2):

"I know I must use the intermediate value theorem but I cant find the x intervals"

Just look for one.  *Any* one.

We can't have $x < 3$ else $(x-3)^{\frac 12}$ is undefined. We want to avoid the issue that $\frac {10}{x-5}$ will tend to negative infinity as $x\to 5^-$ but is discontinuous at $x=5$ and the tends to positive infinty as $x\to 5^+$.  So we want are interval somewhere greater than $5$.  $\frac {10}{x-5}$ will be continuous everywhere $x> 5$.  And so will $(x-3)^{\frac 12}$.

But note $(x-3)^{\frac 12}$ is increasing while $\frac {10}{x-5}$ is decreasing where $x >5$.

So take any $x$ where $\frac {10}{x-5}$ is still larger than $(x-3)^{\frac 12}$.  This should be easy to find because $x\to x^+$, $\frac {10}{x-5}\to \infty$ but $(x-3)^{\frac 12}\to \sqrt 2$ so there are many such values.

$x= 6$ is just fine.  $\frac {10}{6-5} = 10$ while $(6-3)^{\frac 12}=\sqrt 3$, a smaller number.

Now to find the other end we just .... go long.

Let's say $x =500$.  $\frac {10}{500 -5} = \frac {10}{495}$ which is a pretty small number.  Smaller than $1$ at any rate.  While $(500-3)^{\frac 12} =\sqrt{497}$ which is a relatively large number.  Larger that $20$ at any rate.

So.....

At $x =6$ we have $\frac{10}{x-6}= 10 > \sqrt 3 =(x-3)^{\frac 12}$.  And at $x = 500$ we have $\frac {10}{x-6} < 1 < 20 < (x-3)^{\frac 12}$.

Therefore by IVT there is a root in the interval $[6,500]$.

....

Okay, I imagine you're thinking "Aren't I supposed to get closer than that".  To which I answer "Meh... no-one asked us to so we don't have to"

Answer (score 0):

Our requirement is to use the intermediate value theorem to prove that there must be some root between an interval $ (a,b) $.

We must first show that the function is continuous on $ (a,b) $. But that might be better left for later.

I suppose you may just need a reminder about how to pick $ a$ and $b$ to show the existence of a root of a function $ h(x) $ in the interval $(a,b)$

What we need is to know that $ h(x_0) = 0 $ at some $ x_0 \in (a,b) $. Do you think you can figure out how to pick the interval?
Just remember to ensure that $ h(x) $ is continuous on $(a,b)$

Hint: Opposite signs